# Formatting label of bars of BarChart JFreeChart?

Tags: jasper-reports, label, jfreechart, bar-chart

There is very simple question, but I can't found the desicion exactly for jrxml-code.

I have the BarChart with labels of bars and these label must be formatted as percent format not via Java, and in jrxml-code

like this

```
<itemLabel color="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

I suspect that in this tag should be some attribute, that makes it possible.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

With the tags for the bar chart, where you found the itemlabel tag, put this:

```
<valueAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat tickLabelMask="0.0%" verticalTickLabels="false" />
</valueAxisFormat>
```

If you are using the iReports designer, you can just add 0.0% to "Value Axis Tick Label Mask" in the properties panel/window after clicking on the bar chart.

**Note**: that you may need to modify your data, as a value of 5 will be formatted to 500.0%.

Of course you can use different masks #%, 0.00%, #0.0%

Unrelated, but you can expand the axisFormat tag and change the label font if desired by modifying to:

```
<axisFormat tickLabelMask="0.0%" verticalTickLabels="false">
    <labelFont>
        <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
    </labelFont>
</axisFormat>
```

If this option does not work, the work around would be to add a column where your values are stored for percent labels. You can use the "Value Axis Label Expression" to query for the labels.